# Requesting header by name angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an asp.net application that I'm attempting convert the front end to Angular. Getting header information is important to the view. I'm used to getting the header information like so in C#:

```
httpContext.Request.Headers["USERID"]
```

How can I do the same thing in an angular controller?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net each request runs in its own independent context and hence the header access as you have shown in your code make sense.

This does not hold good for angular or in fact any client side framework. You can always get the headers for any request or response made using angular `$http` but the question is which request? During the lifetime of the app you would make many such requests.

Let's say you want to get the current userid, you can create a service that returns the logged in user. There are two ways to implement such a sevice

- create a method on server to return this data. Invoke this method from service and cache results
- on the client side assuming there is a login request made through angular, implement a success callback method which can update the service with the logged user id.

You can look at `$http` documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) to understand how to access headers.